# Position legend in first plot of facet

Tags: r, position, ggplot2, legend

I would like to put my plot legend inside the plot, inside the first plot of a facet.

Here is some example code:

```
df=data.frame(
 x=runif(10),
 y=runif(10),
 facet=rep(c("a","b"),5),
 color=rep(c("red","blue"),5))

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=color))+
 geom_point()+
 facet_wrap(~facet,ncol=1)
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image: plot with legend on outside]

And here is roughly how I would like it to look:

[image: plot with legend inside]

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming your plot is saved as `p`

```
p + theme(
  legend.position = c(0.9, 0.6), # c(0,0) bottom left, c(1,1) top-right.
  legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA)
)
```

If you want the legend background partially transparent, change the `fill` to, e.g., `"#ffffffaa"`.

Comment: Thanks Richie!  That works on my example plot, but for some reason when I add those lines of code to another plot, the legend disappears.  Any idea why that might be?  I put the opts code I have in the original post

Comment: Was the other plot saved to a file type that didn't support transparency (maybe a gif)?

Comment: Or did you change the `legend.position` so that it was moved of the edge of the plot?

Comment: It was moved off the plot...the values in `legend.position` don't agree with the values on the x-axis, for some reason.  I seem to have it now

Comment: The values that legend position uses are relative to the plotting area, so `c(0,0)` is the bottom left of your plot and `c(1,1)` is the top right.  They can't be the same as the values on the x-axis, since different facets can have different scales.

Answer (score 21):

Or, building on @Richie Cotton's answer, since opts is deprecated in ggplot2 now (still assuming your plot is defined as p)

```
p + theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.6)
          ,legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA))
```